# I improved an edit... but did I actually?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I don't know how I did manage to do it.

I just [improved this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7559039)... Oh wait, did I do it actually? I actually simply approved it! You can see it [in the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29420725/revisions). Apparently, I made no changes myself.

But now I'm struggling to understand how *exactly* was I able to do it, because in 79% of cases I am greeted with this message:

> [image]

and in another 20%, this faked "improve" goes through (while I don't change completely *anything*) and I can haz a binding approval vote :D

And in other 1%, [Community just approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7558902) it when I clicked improve (now I know [why it could happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280735)).

So it's definitely a bug, but I can't find the exact way of reproing.

**<sub>Note: earlier there was actually a bug which allowed me to approve an edit by clicking improve and submitting with no changes, then it was fixed and for some time the message I've shown above stopped me constantly, and now there is *another* bug</sub>**

Comment: looks like that happened on my edit I just suggested as well! It says you `Edit`ed but there's no edit from you in the revision history! http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38384. You're cursed...!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes, I was going to note it in my post :) But I didn't find it really strange because I thought it happened as someone else earlier approved it. MSE requires only two votes for the edit to be approved, so it would be approved in any case :)

Comment: Unrelatedly, the bounty notice on this question isn't showing any bounty reason for me. I didn't know it was possible to have a bounty with no reason set.

Comment: @Ben I also didn't know it was possible.

Comment: Nice bump there!

Answer (score 4):

The trick to making this work was to find a suggested edit on a *question* that did not modify the question's *tags*: in this scenario, the logic responsible for comparing your new revision (the Improvement) and the suggested edit fell apart, thinking the tags had changed when they had not.

As of today, this should no longer occur: Improvements must change *something* in the post in order to go through.