# Why/how was this (non wiki) suggested edit orphaned?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, edits, suggested-edits

Reviewing [this (non wiki) suggested edit on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/5764), I hit *Improve Edit* and further updated the post.

Now the suggested edit is "orphaned".  It **shows in [the post history](https://stackapps.com/posts/611/revisions):**

> [image: post history]

but **not in [the review history](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/history):** <sup><sub>(History for all users is shown. You need 10K to see it using the link.)</sub></sup>

> [image: review history]

And [the suggested edit record](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/5764) **shows just the Community User:**

> [image: bad suggested edit record]

when it **should also show the reviewing user**. For example:

> [image: good suggested edit record]

So, **how did this suggested edit get orphaned?**
I've seen this a few times now over the years.

---

PS: If it's not obvious, I am user *Brock Adams* on *Stack Apps*.

Comment: Some race condition similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321562/why-was-a-suggested-edit-approved-despite-a-mods-rejection-and-without-ops-app)?

Comment: @rene, if I read that correctly, then multiple SE's should show in the user activity.  In this case, [they do not](https://stackapps.com/users/34061/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).  Also, at least one of those probably shows in [the Review history](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), although I don't have the rep to verify that there.

Comment: We can leave this one for Shog9 to triage as well. He now knows that code path better then anyone else now, whether he likes it or not ...

Comment: Firelord (a mod on Android.se) confirms that [in that other case, all three suggested edits *do* show in the Review history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321562/why-was-a-suggested-edit-approved-despite-a-mods-rejection-and-without-ops-app?noredirect=1#comment1053056_321562).  So that linked bug seems to be a different beastie.

Comment: I think he is happy to know we have his work laid out for the weekend ...

Comment: @Scott, that looks like the same problem, thanks. So I closed as dupe.  But I don't think that current answer applies to my case at all and it's been almost 3 years and  hasn't been solved (or even addressed by SE).

Comment: (1) Yeah, as I commented on my post, it’s frustrating that, after almost three years, it hasn’t even been given a “[status_XXXXXX]” tag.  Do you (as a high-rep user, and a moderator) have enough clout to rattle some cages and remind people that this is an open problem?  (2) Funny thing: it looks like you wrote the above comment a few (7) seconds before you closed your question.  Of course, closing a question deletes all the “Possible duplicate” comments.  But, even though I still had a comment on your question at the time, I didn’t get notified when you pinged me.  I just happened to check in.

Comment: Donno what you're talking about, that review task looks just fine to me... (I've found the cause of the issue here, will write it up on the dup I guess)

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9, I saw what you did there...